# Is there any way to disable clicking on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a div element which acts as a button. When I click on it, it must be disabled until the animation completes. Presently, I am unbinding it on click and again binds on animation complete which I think is not a good way. Can anyone please suggest is any way to disable the element?

```
function moveLeft() {
    //I unbind the element (div) after clicking on it
    $('#w_oCNABarSlideBack').unbind('click');

    //Write your suggestions above to disable the element
    if(_nBadgeLeft>=0) return;
    else _nBadgeLeft = _nBadgeLeft + _nBadgeWidth;
    $('#w_oCNABarSlider ul').animate({
        left : _nBadgeLeft
    }, 200, function() {
        //again bind the event again on animation complete
        $('#w_oCNABarSlideBack').bind('click', function() { moveLeft(); });

        //Write your suggestions above to enable the element
    });
};
```

Comment: .on and .off may be more up to date

Comment: _"I am using a div element which acts as a button."_ - Why? This will make your page unusable for any users who are physically unable to (or who choose not to) use a mouse or other pointing device.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are absolutely right but tab is disabled in this app.

Comment: CSS [***pointer-events***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: As an aside, note that there's no need for the anonymous function when binding to `moveLeft()`, you can say `.bind('click', moveLeft)` (or `.on('click', moveLeft)` or `.click(moveLeft)`).

Comment: @nnnnnn Apologies, you are right! Actually I did mistake while writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `bind()` and `unbind()` are fine methods and will work. However, you can also disable the element by editing the `.click()` handler, like this

```
$('#w_oCNABarSlideBack').click(function(){return false;});
```

You could also use the similar functions `.on()` and `.off()`, which may be  more up to date

Answer (score 1):

Way to disable element on can be done as follows :

If you're using jQuery versions above 1.4.3:

```
$('selector').click(false);
```

If not:

```
$('selector').click(function(){return false;});
```

try using as above in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest about setting a variable. say `isrunning`.

`isrunning=true` when animation start and you should be setting it to false on animation finish.

And in click function of div, check the variable value. If it is true then return . Else execute the rest code.

Comment: Well said! Basic way to prevent clicking but I was expecting a property in jQuery :(

Comment: @KunJ: Setting variabled to do the stuff is good for code in the context that you dont have to play with events. I believe its just 3 lines of code if you use variable.

Answer (score 0):

Animate function is just enough to complete this task for disabling and enabling buttons on click.See this example code below:

```
$("#divid").click(function(){  // This is the id of div

 $( "#w_oCNABarSlider ul" ).animate({
    left : _nBadgeLeft
  },200, {
     progress: function() {
     $("#w_oCNABarSlideBack").attr("disabled","disabled");
    },
    complete: function() {
      $("#w_oCNABarSlideBack").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't works with div element. Please see nnnnnn comment in answer2.

Comment: OK..Then you can use this animate function inside your function.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this-

```
$('#w_oCNABarSlideBack').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Setting a "disabled" attribute on a div doesn't prevent click events on the div or change its appearance.